# What to do about air gap between basement wall and frame

Tags: insulation, basement

So I have an interesting question that's I'd like to hear from you on. I have a tapered basement wall that has been covered with a waterproof membrane. I plan on attaching 1-2" rigid foam insulation, and then building a framing wall which I'll fill with batt insulation.  What this leaves me with is a very interesting triangular gap between the two layers of insulation. My guess would be around 2" at the top.

Any advice on how (or even if) to fill this gap? Take a look at this diagram! Thanks[image]

Edit: Basement is 3/4 below grade. Climate is Toronto, Ontario, so high humidity in Summer and gets down to -40 in Winter.